# Why does a custom test() function only output first error?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have a class, which among other things stores vectors of a few other objects I have defined. I want to define a `test()` function which checks to see if all the objects are in a valid state and then call this via `assert` so that it only runs in debug mode and outputs each error that is found. However, only the first error is outputted.

Consider the following toy example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int index, int data) : _index(index), _some_data(data) {}

    bool test() const
    {
        bool valid = true;
        if (_some_data == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error! Foo " << _index << " has invalid data.\n";
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

private:
    int _index;
    int _some_data; // for this example, should be non-zero
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<Foo> foos) : _foos(foos) {}

    bool test() const
    {
        bool valid = true;
        for (auto &foo : _foos)
        {
            valid = valid && foo.test();
        }
        return valid;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Foo> _foos;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1(0, 0);
    Foo foo2(1, 0);
    Foo foo3(2, 0);

    std::vector<Foo> foos({foo1, foo2, foo3}); // all three foos in invalid state

    MyClass my_class(foos);
    assert(my_class.test()); // outputs "Error! Foo 0 has invalid data." But does not show me errors in other two foos
}
```

Why does this output only the first invalid Foo and not every invalid Foo?

I guess this has something to do with the compiler trying to optimise the code (I'm running GCC). As soon as `valid` is equal to `false` it does not bother running the rest of the loop. How do I prevent this?

Comment: You cannot prevent this, short circuiting is mandated by standard. The loop is run as regular, but for every `valid && foo.test();` in second and later loop iterations compiler determines that `valid` is `false` and thus the whole expression is `false`. The only way to make sure each function call happens would be to store result in temporary variable first: `bool test = foo.test(); valid = valid && test;`

Comment: Okay thanks. I had a look at the similar question that was linked and it says to use & instead of &&. This now works.